# @ConditionalOnProperty with @Scheduled is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'd like to trigger a specific scheduled function if a property is present.

My properties are following:

```
tasks:
    task1:
        interval: "* * * ? * *"
    task2:
        interval: "0 * * ? * *"
```

Those are my functions:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${tasks.task1.interval}")
public void doTask1()
{
    // do something
}

@Scheduled(cron = "${tasks.task2.interval}")
public void doTask2()
{
    // do something
}
```

What I like to achive is that doTask2() is not triggering if task2 property is not specified.

Properties:

```
tasks:
    task1:
        interval: "* * * ? * *"
```

Functions:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "tasks.task1")
@Scheduled(cron = "${tasks.task1.interval}")
public void doTask1()
{
    // do something
}



@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "tasks.task2")
@Scheduled(cron = "${tasks.task2.interval}")
public void doTask2()
{
    // do something
}
```

If I try this setup, I allways get following error:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'tasks.task2.interval' in value "${tasks.task2.interval}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--):

> The special value "-" indicates a disabled cron trigger, primarily meant for externally specified values resolved by a ${...} placeholder.

You could use a default minus value for the cron expression:

`@Scheduled(cron = "${tasks.task2.interval:-}")`

More info on default values can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-defaults).